# What to do after this last step?

Tags: fourier-series, complex

I am solving a question from book in which I have to use summation. It is as follows:

$$ \frac{1}{10}\sum_{n=0}^{9}  e^{-jk\omega_0n}          $$
The value of $\omega_0$ is $\frac{2\pi}{10}$.
What I have done so far is:

$$   \frac{1}{10} \left(\frac{1-e^{-9jk\frac{2\pi}{10}}.e^{jk\frac{2\pi}{10}}} {1-e^{-jk\frac{2\pi}{10}}}\right)$$

After this step I am stuck and can not figure out the next step?

Comment: I believe the solution can be found by considering the fact that the exponential expressions represent complex numbers which can be intuitively added in the [complex plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_plane). Hint: what is the sum of $e^{0} + e^{-j\pi}$?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This sum appears quite often in DSP.

\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} \exp(-j\alpha n) &\stackrel{(a)}{=} \frac{1- \exp(-j\alpha N)}{1 - \exp(-j\alpha )}\\
&= \frac{e^{-j\alpha N/2}(e^{+j\alpha N/2}- e^{-j\alpha N/2})}{e^{-j\alpha /2}(e^{+j\alpha /2}- e^{-j\alpha /2})}\\
&\stackrel{(b)}{=} e^{-j\frac{\alpha}{2}(N-1)} \frac{\sin(N\alpha/2)}{\sin(\alpha/2)}
\end{align}
where the last step $(b)$ comes from identity $e^{+j\theta}-e^{-j\theta} = 2j\sin(\theta)$ and be careful at $(a)$ as Matt's comment.

Substitute $\alpha=k\omega_0=k\frac{2\pi}{N}$, $\sin(N\alpha/2)=\sin(k\pi)=0$ if $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ hence so is the sum.

---

### Update for $\alpha=0$

It is trivial that $\exp(-j\alpha n) \stackrel{\alpha=0}{=} 1$ then the sum equals $N$.

It can be thought as the case of the final result after $(b)$  when $\alpha \to 0$ then
$$e^{-j\frac{\alpha}{2}(N-1)} \frac{\sin(N\alpha/2)}{\sin(\alpha/2)} \stackrel{\alpha \to 0}{\to} N$$
where the limit is evaluated by [L'Hôpital's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule).

---

Further interesting discussion can be found in [Laurent Duval's answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/53291/26081).

Comment: Note that technically speaking your first equation is not correct for $\alpha =0$ (i.e., $k=0$ in the OP's example), because you're dividing by zero; luckily, in the final formula, $\alpha=0$ leads to the correct result if taken as a limit. That's also why most people never realize / don't care.

Comment: it's true @MattL.

Comment: @MattL. Is it really *luckily* or will it always be the same when taken as a limit ? Are there any such summation formulas (in the context of DSP) that you know which do not equate to their L'Hopital limits at the 0/0 condition ?

Comment: @Fat32: Luckily in the sense that we are lucky that we don't need to worry, not in the sense "by chance". Of course it's no coincidence that the limit exists and gives the only reasonable value, but the sum of the original sequence (with integer $k$) is not a function but a sequence of values for each value of $k$, so making it a function and working with limits is a slightly perverted way of dealing with it (especially if the direct and exact solution for $k=0$ is so simple).

Comment: @MattL. Yes, treating a discrete-index sequence as a continuous argument function is not the best way especially when there is the very simple and formally satifying solution as you stated...

Comment: I would argue that the OP did not claim $k$ was integer.

Comment: @AlexTP,It does not matter whether $k$ is an integer.  What matters is if $ k \cdot \omega_0 $ is a multiple of $2\pi$.  In which case, it is much simpler to go back to the original summation than it is to take the limit.

Comment: @CedronDawg I do not say the opposite. Just want to reaffirm a part of Matt L.'s statement "it's no coincidence that the limit exists and gives the only reasonable value" and to disagree the other parts.

Comment: @AlexTP: Engineers using $k$ as a continuous (real) variable shouldn't be trusted ;) And, what is more, that formula looks very much like a DFT of a quite simple sequence, in which case $k$ would indeed be integer. But, you're right, who am I to assume anything that is not explicitly stated in the question!?

Comment: @MattL. out of the scope of this specific question, I do totally agree with all your comments :)

Answer (score 3):

As a good answer has been given by [@AlexTP](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/53279/15892), I'll go from the detail to a larger picture.

Although the "[De L'Hospital's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule)" seems attractive, it should be handled with a lot of care (see my answer to [Why does L'Hopital's rule fail in this case?](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1711246/257503)), because it requires somehow strong conditions!

I do recommend to use weaker conditions instead, when one can. And with sines of positive arguments  around zero $(0\le x\le\epsilon)$, luckily, one can the standard simple bounds:

$$ x(1-x^2/6) \le \sin(x) \le x$$

which suffice to bound the sine ratio $\frac{\sin(N\alpha/2)}{\sin(\alpha/2)}$ as $\alpha \to 0$ with $N$ given. More precisely, for  both $0\le \alpha/2\le\epsilon$ and $0\le N\alpha/2\le\epsilon$, we have

$$ N\alpha/2(1-(N\alpha/2)^2/6) \le \sin(N\alpha/2) \le N\alpha/2$$
and 
$$ \frac{1}{\alpha/2} \le \frac{1}{\sin(\alpha/2)} \le \frac{1}{\alpha/2(1-(\alpha/2)^2/6)}$$

thus

$$ N(1-(N\alpha/2)^2/6) \le \frac{\sin(N\alpha/2)}{\sin(\alpha/2)} \le \frac{N}{(1-(\alpha/2)^2/6)}\,,$$
whose central term thus tends to $N$ as $\alpha \to 0_+$. And you can plug it into [AlexTP](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/users/26081/alextp) solution.

What is important here is that the underlying  function of $k$ (just suppose $k \in \mathbb{R}$) is obviously continuous, as it is a finite sum of   ($N=10$) continuous functions $f_n(k)=\exp(-jk w_0 n)$ (this could not work with infinite sums, as an infinite sum of continuous functions might be discontinuous, especially if the convergence is not uniform).

So, you can conveniently use the geometric sum formula anywhere it holds (with a non-zero denominator), and just use the limit (as the function IS continuous) otherwise.

**This sum of an exponential geometric series  is important**: it is the discrete equivalent to the Fourier transform of a continuous rectangular window. The former yields [a sinc, a cardinal sine](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/Interpolation/The_Sinc_Function_Cardinal.html). Your formula, for a [discrete rectangular window](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/sasp/Rectangular_Window.html), yield a (phased) discrete sinc called *aliased sinc* (asinc) or *periodized  sinc*  (psync), with details on the [JOS website signal processing site](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/sasp/Rectangular_Window.html).

Comment: [off topic] adding an infinitely many continuous functions can produce a discontinuous resultant ? Such as the ideal LPF frequency response. But according to **mathematical induction**, it should be continuous too? So why is mathmeatical induction failing here? Do you know conditions on which mathematical induction can be applied or not? According to m.induction, if sum of two continuous functions are continuous -which is-, then the sum of N cont.func. will be also continuous for all N. So why is the contradiction ?

Comment: From my forgotten past, if the convergence is uniform, then the resulting function is continuous as well. The set of natural number $\mathbb{N}$ does not contains infinity. Another example: a finite sum of rationals is rational. But $1-\frac{1}{3}+ \frac{1}{5} - \cdots \to \pi/4$.

Comment: Second thought: it is more about the notion of limit. Continuity does not always hold under limits. Infinite sums are special cases of limits

Comment: so we agree on the **failure of induction** ?

Comment: @Fat32, This is the very question that spawned Real Analysis (my least favorite math courses).  There is not a failure of induction.  The limit case is not part of the sequence.  The limit of a sequence of continuous functions can be a discontinuous functions, but the limit is never reached it is only approached.  It's one of those epsilon and delta arguments.

Comment: @CedronDawg Calculus, Analysis and Topology are like in opposition with algebra. I'm not sure what to say as the concept of infinity is almost non-mathematical.

Comment: Infinity can be treated, as in Non-standard analysis, but it usually requires an additional set of axioms